# Need to remove '#" symbol when it is come at the end of the link

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to remove "#" symbol, when its coming in the end of the hyperlink.

My Input xml is:

```
<Uri>http://www.tneb.nih.gov/lifeafter#</Uri>
```

XSL I used as:

```
   <xsl:template match="Uri">
      <xref format="html" href="{.}" outputclass="">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xref>
   </xsl:template>
```

Output I'm getting as:

```
<xref format="html"
               href="http://www.tneb.nih.gov/lifeafter#"
               outputclass="">http://www.tneb.nih.gov/lifeafter#</xref>
```

Expected output:

```
<xref format="html"
               href="http://www.tneb.nih.gov/lifeafter"
               outputclass="">http://www.tneb.nih.gov/lifeafter#</xref>
```

I need to remove "#" symbol at the end of the "href" attribute. not with the internal text. Please suggest me coding for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<xref format="html" href="{replace(., '#$', '')}" outputclass="">
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you always have a hash (#) character at the end try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., '#')"/>
```

Comment: if you use substring function than "#"  it can cause for data deletion if "#" is appear in between text, as mentioned in question

Comment: Yes @clogwog. Its deleting from the data

Comment: ah i didn't realize you can have a hash (#) character inside a url. i thought it was only used for bookmarks at the end.